# how to integrate facebook chat in windows application using C#

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

hey can any one tell me how can i integrate facebook chat in windows c# or how can i make the application in c# to use facebook chat it will be better if any one can give me code or start up thing or any link that will help me so i can make that type of application thanks in advance

i read some where that XMPP allow that thing but how to use that in dotnet c# to chat on facebook.

Answer (score 5):

Facebook allowed its chat api access through XMPP look at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

Some of the C# clients for xmpp:

http://www.ag-software.de/agsxmpp-sdk/

http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/

http://www.ag-software.de/matrix-xmpp-sdk/

http://coversant.net/product/studio-overview.aspx

**Note :** JID : facebook_username@chat.facebook.com

Comment: can you give me the samplevcode link also or may be code you have i checked that links all ready but didn't know how to get benefits from it

Comment: You can explore jabber-net. Here is the code documentation http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/wiki/SendMessage. And, remember server is chat.facebook.com and TARGET user have facebook_username@chat.facebook.com format.

Comment: thanks bro that is nice example can you tell me how to get the online user list from facebook also

Comment: Dude, Just explore PresenceManager in the library. :)

Comment: hi @Gagandeep Singh i tried what you give me but it is giving this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/706/79189305.png/
i did this check this 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/401/83310812.png/